# How to access a JSON object that is inside an object having no name

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, nullpointerexception

I have this `JSON`

```
{
    "success": true,
    "shippingMethod": [
        {
            "flat": {
                "code": "flat.flat",
                "title": "Flat Shipping Rate",
                "cost": "5.00",
                "tax_class_id": "9",
                "text": "$5.00"
            }
        },
        {
            "zajil": {
                "code": "zajil.zajil",
                "title": "Zajil Shipping",
                "cost": "26",
                "tax_class_id": "0",
                "text": "$26.00"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Notice** that every real `object` in `array` is within an unnecessary object that has no name i.e. `flat` and `zajil` in the above code are in another object.
I just need the data within those nested objects `flat` and `zajil`. When I try this code

```
JSONArray shippingMethods = response.optJSONArray("shippingMethod");
          for (int i = 0; i < shippingMethods.length(); i++) {
          JSONObject shippingObj = shippingMethods.optJSONObject(i);
          JSONObject shippingMethod = shippingObj.optJSONObject("");
          Iterator<?> keys = shippingObj.keys();
             shippingMethod.optString("title");
             shippingMethod.optString("cost");
       }
```

I supposed I can get the `Object` that has no name like

```
JSONObject shippingMethod = shippingObj.optJSONObject("");
```

But it does not work and throw `NullPointerException` when getting something from it. Then I try to `iterate` for `keys` like

```
Iterator<?> keys = shippingObj.keys();
```

It does not show anything as this object does not contain any key directly. So My question is how can I get the required data `title` and `cost` from the above `JSON`.
**I can't** change `JSON` as it is the default structure of the customer's website.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to access a JSON object that is inside an object having no name

All the objects have names in your JSON.

> I just need the data within those nested objects flat and zajil.

`flat` and `zajil` are the names of the objects. The fact that you happen to not care about those names does not mean that the names do not exist.

If your JSON is set up that each of those objects contains exactly one nested object, use [`keys()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#keys()) or [`names()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#names()) to find the name, then retrieve the object by that name. You are trying to retrieve the object by `""`, and neither `flat` nor `zajil` are `""`.

> It does not show anything as this object does not contain any key directly

Yes, it does. The keys are `flat` and `zajil`, respectively.

When `i` is `0`, `shippingMethods.optJSONObject(i)` will return a `JSONObject` containing:

```
    {
        "flat": {
            "code": "flat.flat",
            "title": "Flat Shipping Rate",
            "cost": "5.00",
            "tax_class_id": "9",
            "text": "$5.00"
        }
    }
```

Calling `keys()` on that `JSONObject` will return an `Iterator`; if you get the first value from it, that value will be `flat`.

Comment: Thanks @CmmonsWare but the problem is those objects `flat` and `zajil` are within another parent object that is causing problem, that has no name.

Comment: @InzimamTariqIT: You are getting those by index from the `JSONArray` (`shippingMethods.optJSONObject(i)`).

Comment: I used `Iterator<?> keys = shippingObj.keys();` in my code & printed out keys but does not observed keys in logcat so I get confused. Now I filtered my logcat the keys are there.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this, may help you

```
//get response
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("response");

//get status
boolean success = jsonObject.getBoolean("success");

if(success){
    //get jsonarray from response
    JSONArray shippingMethodArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("shippingMethod");

    //iterate array
    for(int i=0; i<shippingMethodArray.length(); i++){

        jsonObject = shippingMethodArray.getJSONObject(i);

        //get all keys from jsonObject
        List<String> allKeys = getAllKeys(jsonObject);

        //iterate all keys
        for(String key: allKeys) {

            //get jsonObject by key
            jsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject(key);

            //get data
            String title = jsonObject.getString("title");
            String cost = jsonObject.getString("cost");
        }
    }
}else {
    //do if not success...
}


//returns all keys from jsonobjects
private List<String> getAllKeys(JSONObject jsonObject) throws JSONException{
    List<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>();

    Iterator<?> iterator = jsonObject.keys();
    while( iterator.hasNext() ) {
        String key = (String)iterator.next();
        keys.add(key);
    }
    return keys;
}
```

Comment: Thanks +1 for your help. I already had the working code But get confused when looking at logcat. When I filtered my logcat I saw My code was fine & working as expected